# RDMA - how does the ibv_post_send know the CQ?

Tags: c, linux, rdma

I'm trying to learn RDMA.

My question is, when doing [ibv_post_send](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ibv_post_send), I should get a completion event on a completion queue. But how does the *ibv_post_send* know to which completion queue? From what I see here, I could have created [many](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ibv_get_cq_event).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [when initiating a QP](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ibv_create_qp), it can be assigned to a send CQ and recv CQ in its init attributes.